# Selecting hr in HTML, seems to select in reverse order?

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to select everything between a `<div>` with a certain class and the first `<hr>` after it.

With this query:

`//div[@id='a']/*[preceding::div/@class='b' and following:hr[0]]`

And this example HTML:

```
<div id="a">div a
    <div class="b">div b</div>
    <p>1</p>
    text1
    <a>2</a>
    text2
    <div>3</div>
    <hr>
    <div>4</div>
    <hr>
    <div>5</div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

I get everything between the `div` with class "b" and the *last* `hr`. Selecting with `hr[*n*]` seems to select in reverse order. `... and following::hr[last()]]` selects up to the last hr as well, which is what I would've expected. With this example, `... and following::hr[2]` will select up to the first `hr`, but in practice I don't have any guarantee of how many there will be. How can I select up to that first `hr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly, `following::hr[0]` is always an empty sequence because nodes are numbered from 1; so this part of the condition is false, so your query should select nothing.

But actually you wrote `following:hr[0]`, which should be a syntax error unless you have declared the namespace prefix "following". Somehow I don't think the code you are showing us is the code you executed.

Now let's suppose you changed it to `following::hr[1]`. This would select everything provided it has a following element called hr, that is, everything up to the last `hr`, which is the symptom you are describing.

To select nodes before the first hr, select those that don't have a preceding hr, that is, `not(preceding::hr)`.

Except that I suspect all your "following" and "preceding" axes should be `following-sibling` and `preceding-sibling`.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. The following::hr[0] was a typo, it was supposed to be (and in my code was) following::hr[1].

Comment: Followup: I've edited the example HTML to add some bare text nodes before the first `<hr>`. How can I select these as well? I thought of `//div[@id='a']/*[preceding::div/@class='b' and not(preceding::hr]] | //div[@id='a']/text()[preceding::div/@class='b' and not(preceding::hr)]` but that still doesn't select the bare text; however, `//div[@id='a']/text()[preceding::div/@class='b' and not(preceding::hr)]` does select **just** the bare text.

Comment: If you want to select all nodes, and not just nodes of the main node type for a given axis, use `node()` instead of `*`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that editing a question after it has been answered, unless it's simply to correct spellings etc, creates immense confusion for anyone coming back to the thread later. If I tried to answer your amended question here, no-one would be able to make sense of it. Ask a new question instead.